# Unable to access Jenkins remotely using IIS reverse proxy

Tags: iis, jenkins, reverse-proxy

I have Jenkins setup on a Windows 2012 R2 server as a service with Application Request Routing installed, Reverse Proxy enabled, and the following URL Rewrite set to a domain in IIS: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/{R:0}`

Jenkins is running on port 8080. IIS is running on port 80.

For the sake of this question, we'll say my domain name on IIS is example.com that I am having Jenkins reverse proxied through.

I can access the Jenkins site typing in either example.com or localhost:8080 on my Windows server. I cannot access it outside of my Windows server.

To make sure I had everything setup in IIS correctly & no firewall issues, I turned off the Jenkins service, created a Node.js server and tested that with the exact same proxy service on port 8080 using the same domain name. That worked perfectly.

I have also created a Frankenstein setup where IIS reverse proxies requests to a Node.js server. The Node.js server reverse proxies the requests to the Jenkins service. This solution works perfectly as well everywhere. This is all running on the same machine, using different ports for each one. It's not ideal.

I'm using Jenkins 2.2.

I do not receive any errors when trying to access the site. It eventually just times out.